# Trying to create a calendar using switch and if statement to check user input then outputs the day

Tags: c++, if-statement, calendar, switch-statement

So I'm trying to create a calendar that asks for the user's chosen month and date numerically using switch statement and then I tried to use if statement to check the user's date input and if it matches it displays the day.

When i run it it always prints Sunday even though i inputted the date for a Monday.  What am I missing?

Here is my code

```
    void UserInput()
    {
    cout << "\nPlease enter a numerical value of a month e.g. May=5, December=12: \n";
    cin >>  Month;

    cout << "\nPlease enter a Date: \n";
    cin >>  Date;
    }

    void MagicCalendar()
    {
    switch(Month)
    {
    case 1:
    if(Date == 6 || 13 || 20 || 27)
    {
    cout << " It's Sunday!!!";
    break;
    } 
    if(Date == 7 || 14 || 21 || 28 )   <-- the problem is probably here idk if its the operand or the if statement itself
    {
    cout << " It's a MOFO MONDAY GO KYS NOW!";
    break;
    }
    else if(Date ==)
    {
    cout << " It's a Tuesday and kinda like a monday but yeah...";
    break;
    }
    else if(Date ==)
    {
    cout << " It's Wednesday and I know that you can feel it!";
    break;
    }
    else if(Date ==)
    {
    cout << " It's a THURSDAY!! getting warmer :D";
    break;
    }
     else if(Date ==)
    {
    cout << " It's FRIDAY!! GO GET SHITFACED YOU DESERVE IT :D";
    break;
    }
    else if(Date ==)
    {
    cout << " It's SATURDAY BABY! go cry in a corner while suffering from Hungover...";
    break;
    }
    break;    
}
}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you edit your original question and make it clear what you're asking, and give more details (i.e. of the error, and what you expect to happen vs what happens). Needs more clarity. Also, I think your syntax is just incorrect. When you use are using an if *statement*, you need to include the entire statement after each 'or' operator `||`, not just the value, so `if (Date == 7 || Date == 14)` is correct but `if (Date == 7 || 14)` isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(Date == 6 || 13 || 20 || 27)
```

Wrong syntax

Correct:

```
if(Date == 6 || Date == 13 || Date == 20 || Date == 27)
```

Similar to other lines in your code.

Comment: OMG that did the trick I've been trying to figure this out for like 6 hrs now....... THANK YOU SO MUCHHH

Comment: For some reason when I input  (2) February which is case 2 it doesnt output anything, it only works when i call (1) january. And im sorry if i dont know how to use this platform as I am a newbie here Thank you  for the patience and all the help :)

Comment: But your code doesn't check for February, only for dates in January.

Comment: I made this and tried it, switch(Month)
{
  case 2:  //for february 
  if(Date == 3 ||Date == 10 ||Date == 17 ||Date == 24)
{
  cout << " It's Sunday2!!!";
  break;
}
}
  if(Date == 7 ||Date == 14 ||Date == 21 ||Date == 28 )
{
  cout << " It's a MOFO MONDAY GO KYS NOW!";
  break;
}

Comment: Don't merge switches and ifs. Use if (Motth == 1) and then correct braces and indentation so you don't lose your way.